# How can i compare in app appointment time is more then firebase database time or less then database time

Tags: firebase-realtime-database, comparison

I have an app where anybody can book an appointment for a coach by pick time like 1:00pm to 1:30pm.
But here I want to check if 1:00pm to 1:30pm is already booked so nobody should booked time after 1:00pm and before 1:30pm.
[image]

This is my database structure Please anybody can solve this so help me..

Comment: So what have you tried so far to achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

In your current data structure, the only option is to load all the booking and check in your application code whether any of them are in the slot you are looking for.

If you want to instead be able to query the database whether the slot is already booked, you will have to (also) store a list booking in the database in a format that is suitable for your query needs.

For example, given the use-case you mention, you could store:

```
bookedTimes: {
  "2022-10-24 09:00-09:30": "E3..the UID"
}
```

With a structure like this, you can now quickly look up whether a specific 30m time slot on a specific day is booked.

Adding additional data structures like this for specific use-cases is quite common in NoSQL, where your data model reflects the use-cases of your app. To learn more about this, I recommend reading [NoSQL data modeling](https://highlyscalable.wordpress.com/2012/03/01/nosql-data-modeling-techniques/) and also watching [Firebase for SQL developers](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLl-K7zZEsYLlP-k-RKFa7RyNPa9_wCH2s).